# Magento 2.3 Topmenu override declaration error

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.1, megamenu, magento2.3.2

**Declaration** of `_getHtml`

Should be compatible with `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getHtml(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, array $colBrakes = Array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega.php

```
protected function _getHtml(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    array $colBrakes = []
)
```

Also replace :

```
$colStops = null; to $colStops = [];
```