# Topmenu override declaration error Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, overrides, topmenu

Topmenu override declaration getting error in  Magento 2.3

Comment: Can you please provide more detail?

Comment: attach error or code

Comment: reference=> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280771/magento-2-3-topmenu-override-declaration-error